# Part of my base url is removed upon adding a relative path

Tags: c#, uri, rest-client, base-url

I have a base url https://dev.services.com/this/is/nothing/
and the path "max/status"

When I try to add "max/status" to the base url the part this/is/nothing/ is removed. This just happens some times not always.

I am doing this:

```
IRestClient _builder;
var baseUrl = "https://dev.services.com/this/is/nothing/";
var nextUrl = "max/status";
var fullUrl = new Uri(baseUrl, nextUrl);
var client = new _builder.Build(fullUrl);
```

the result should be https://dev.services.com/this/is/nothing/max/status
but now is: https://dev.services.com/max/status

so, obviously I am getting an error because https://dev.services.com/this/is/nothing/max/status does not exist.

any idea?

Comment: This would not even compile as there is no `Uri` constructor taking two string arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample would not compile in its current form. To achieve your desired result, you'd need to change it like this:

```
var baseUrl = new Uri("https://dev.services.com/this/is/nothing/");
var fullUrl = new Uri(baseUrl, "max/status");
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. A question about that. Why the base url must be Uri? I thought that it could be var fullUrl = new Uri(baseUrl, "max/status");

Comment: i am using this constructor Uri(Uri, String)

Comment: @KarlaFlores Both of your constructor arguments are strings. So you aren't.

Comment: I understand.
So, what is better to use:

Comment: Is there a difference between to use:
var baseUrl = new Uri("base/url");
var fullUrl = new Uri(baseUrl, "max/status");
 AND
var fullUrl = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl, "max/status"));
neither of them work but just curious